# program.exe has stopped working ...pls find mistake?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, codeblocks

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int m,n,m1,n1,a[m][n],b[m1][n1],s=0,i,j,c[m][n1],i1,j1;
printf("Enter no. of rows...& no. of columns..of 1st matrix");
scanf("%d",&m);
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter no. of rows...& no. of columns..of 2nd matrix");
scanf("%d",&m1);
scanf("%d",&n1);
if(n!=m1){
    printf("Matrix multiplication can't be performed.Please check the order 
of the matrices.");
}
else{
    for(i=1;i<=m;i+=1){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j+=1){
            s+=a[i][j]*b[j][i];
        }
for(i1=1;i1<=m;i1+=1){
for(j1=1;j1<=n1;j1+=1){
    c[i1][j1]=s;
    printf("%d",c[i1][j1]);
}
printf("\n");
}
    }

}



}
```

when i buid it ..it shows no error
but while running the code it is showing that the .exe has stopped working
pls mention the mistakes in my code....the previous programs that i've runned in codeblocks ide have been executed correctly.....

Comment: For one thing, you are accessing beyond your array. That causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: pls..can you give a clear explaination...i'm a beginner..

Comment: @Nitesh please first read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: The first error is in the third line. `a[m][n]` doesn't mean "make the array `a` as large as `m` and `n` *will dictate in the future*". (`void main()` is non-standard too but your compiler lets you get away with it). Enable warnings for your compiler and treat them as errors.

Comment: This code is hard to read. Please apply proper indentation. Did the compiler give some warnings to you?

Answer (score 2):

Currently your code looks like this (I've trimmed down the number of variables to make it easier to read).

```
int m,n;
int a[m][n];
printf("Enter no. of rows...& no. of columns..of 1st matrix");
scanf("%d",&m);
scanf("%d",&n);
```

When you declare the array `a`, the values of `m` and `n` aren't defined - they could be any value that would fit into an `int`. They might be 0 for example and that would mean you've declared `a` as `a[0][0]`. You then get values for `m` and `n`, by which stage it's too late. Either way your code will be suffering undefined behaviour.

One possibly solution is to allocate memory for the matrices like this...

```
int m,n;
int **a;
printf("Enter no. of rows...& no. of columns..of 1st matrix");
scanf("%d",&m);
scanf("%d",&n);
a=malloc(sizeof(*a)*m);
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
  a[i]=malloc(sizeof(*a[i])*n);
  }
```

You'd need to remember to `free()` the memory allocated after you've finished using it.